# WSO2IS: SAML request encoding / decoding

Tags: authentication, decode, encode, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

I am using WSO2 Identity Server 4.1.0. I have successfully followed the steps described [here (thank you)](http://wso2.com/library/articles/2010/07/saml2-web-browser-based-sso-wso2-identity-server) to get a local SAML2 consumer to work with a local WSO2 Identity Server.

The steps mentioned above describe using a Tomcat webapp to 'call' the login page of the WSO2 Identity server, using a SAML request. The webapp will also receive a SAML response. The webapp has to generate this SAML request, so that it contains a valid issuer, timestamp, etc. Without this request, the Identity Server will not provide a login page. So actually, the request is a sort of preperation. The SAML request is encoded.

My aim is to get a better understand of the way in which this webapp is composing the initial SAML request. I was only able to see the request, after using SAML debugger. How can I view this SAML request manually, using decoders?

*What I have learned so far:*

- I have learned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8150096/construct-a-signed-saml2-logout-request) that we can use [SAML 2.0 Debugger](https://rnd.feide.no/simplesaml/module.php/saml2debug/debug.php) to decode or encode the saml requests and responses. But I would like to how and what is getting encoded / decoded.
- I have learned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16105477/saml-2-0-request-encoding/) that a URL decoder and Base64 decode might be needed. So I was able to URL decode the `/samlsso?SAMLRequest`. It contained an encoded `assertionString`. I was not able to Base64 decode this string.

Request HTTP Header:
This request is send to the WSO2 Identity Server.

```
https://localhost:9443/samlsso

POST /samlsso HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9443
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: nl,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Referer: https://localhost:9443/samlsso?SAMLRequest=jZPBbtswDIZfRdA9seO0WyzEKbIUxQx0m5u4O%2BymyswiQJY8kU6zt5%2Fs2GsORdCrSP7k%2F5Fa3p1qw47gUTub8dk05gyscpW2vzP%2BXD5MFvxutURZm0asWzrYLfxpAYmFOouiD2S89VY4iRqFlTWgICV262%2BPIpnGovGOnHKGszUieAqNNs5iW4PfgT9qBc%2Fbx4wfiBoRRcYpaQ4OSSziRRx1%2Bsm0gtpFaigKOkRev7QEZ50w6iCU2wpOwUUyT5Ob2%2FQm5ezBeQX94BnfS4PAWX6f8WAzx0Ii6iO8BRDboIEkLWU8iWfzSfx5EidlnIp5Ima300%2Bz9BdnxeDoi7ZnTtfsv5yTUHwty2JS%2FNiVnP0ceYcEPtLtu%2FuPc5UjTb56o7SMLsVG6e%2BhOL8vnNHqL1sb4143HiQF5%2BRb6CHVkq636150Ndn3qaLpHCCBJc52Raf%2F1Eqj9xp8xvNuMh6N3YeLgapfQ9gZwYnYxtWN9Bo7DHCSigYQ4jJrY4LLLewvqHwYytU0JVQnHZ67I3h1vuqWCipMWXppsXGezizfnWc1cn7X2%2F%2Fo5YdZ%2FQM%3D&RelayState=null
Cookie: MSG13721655096400.5456646701125957=true; MSG13721655827030.13073174051588388=true; MSG13721677790000.949325276640498=true; menuPanel=visible; menuPanelType=main; current-breadcrumb=manage_menu%2Cmanage_saml_sso%23; requestedURI=../../carbon/admin/index.jsp; Modernizr=; JSESSIONID=E4B3DB007762167497588E63D2C396F6; MSG13727573306230.10612530425878663=true; region1_manage_menu=visible; ssoTokenId=E4B3DB007762167497588E63D2C396F6
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 806
username=admin&assertnConsumerURL=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fsaml2.demo%2Fconsumer&issuer=saml2.demo&id=0&subject=null&relyingPartySessionId=null&assertionString=jZPBbtswDIZfRdA9seO0WyzEKbIUxQx0m5u4O%2BymyswiQJY8kU6zt5%2Fs2GsORdCrSP7k%2F5Fa3p1qw47gUTub8dk05gyscpW2vzP%2BXD5MFvxutURZm0asWzrYLfxpAYmFOouiD2S89VY4iRqFlTWgICV262%2BPIpnGovGOnHKGszUieAqNNs5iW4PfgT9qBc%2Fbx4wfiBoRRcYpaQ4OSSziRRx1%2Bsm0gtpFaigKOkRev7QEZ50w6iCU2wpOwUUyT5Ob2%2FQm5ezBeQX94BnfS4PAWX6f8WAzx0Ii6iO8BRDboIEkLWU8iWfzSfx5EidlnIp5Ima300%2Bz9BdnxeDoi7ZnTtfsv5yTUHwty2JS%2FNiVnP0ceYcEPtLtu%2FuPc5UjTb56o7SMLsVG6e%2BhOL8vnNHqL1sb4143HiQF5%2BRb6CHVkq636150Ndn3qaLpHCCBJc52Raf%2F1Eqj9xp8xvNuMh6N3YeLgapfQ9gZwYnYxtWN9Bo7DHCSigYQ4jJrY4LLLewvqHwYytU0JVQnHZ67I3h1vuqWCipMWXppsXGezizfnWc1cn7X2%2F%2Fo5YdZ%2FQM%3D&RelayState=null&password=admin
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Set-Cookie: ssoTokenId=E4B3DB007762167497588E63D2C396F6; Expires=Tue, 02-Jul-2013 19:32:45 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Tue, 02 Jul 2013 09:32:45 GMT
Server: WSO2 Carbon Server
```

The 'referer' in the request above contains a SAML request, that was made visible by the SAML Debugger.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<samlp:AuthnRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" AssertionConsumerServiceURL="http://localhost:8080/saml2.demo/consumer" AttributeConsumingServiceIndex="1239245949" ForceAuthn="false" ID="0" IsPassive="false" IssueInstant="2013-07-02T09:32:15.619Z" ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Version="2.0">
    <samlp:Issuer xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">saml2.demo</samlp:Issuer>
    <samlp:NameIDPolicy AllowCreate="true" Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent" SPNameQualifier="Isser"/>
    <samlp:RequestedAuthnContext Comparison="exact">
        <saml:AuthnContextClassRef xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
    </samlp:RequestedAuthnContext>
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

(It seems it is not the full SAML request yet, and that the WSO2 IS is composing the complete SAML Request internally.)

Response HTTP Header:
This is the response received from the WSO2 Identity Server.

```
http://localhost:8080/saml2.demo/consumer

POST /saml2.demo/consumer HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: nl,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cookie: JSESSIONID=E078F376C8ED303D28A200DD7AC28324; MSG13721655096400.5456646701125957=true; MSG13721655827030.13073174051588388=true; MSG13721677790000.949325276640498=true; menuPanel=visible; menuPanelType=main; current-breadcrumb=manage_menu%2Cmanage_saml_sso%23; requestedURI=../../carbon/admin/index.jsp; Modernizr=; MSG13727573306230.10612530425878663=true; region1_manage_menu=visible; ssoTokenId=E4B3DB007762167497588E63D2C396F6
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 1870
SAMLResponse=%3C%3Fxml+version%3D%221.0%22+encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Csaml2p%3AResponse+ID%3D%22dnfomflkhhdjjgfoggoagcdopgnjmpajenlehbka%22+IssueInstant%3D%222013-07-02T09%3A32%3A45.635Z%22+Version%3D%222.0%22+xmlns%3Asaml2p%3D%22urn%3Aoasis%3Anames%3Atc%3ASAML%3A2.0%3Aprotocol%22%3E%3Csaml2p%3AStatus%3E%3Csaml2p%3AStatusCode+Value%3D%22urn%3Aoasis%3Anames%3Atc%3ASAML%3A2.0%3Astatus%3ASuccess%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsaml2p%3AStatus%3E%3Csaml2%3AAssertion+ID%3D%22dgamkdkadflnniggkelmjfakjljedhfdhnbpomdk%22+IssueInstant%3D%222013-07-02T09%3A32%3A45.635Z%22+Version%3D%222.0%22+xmlns%3Asaml2%3D%22urn%3Aoasis%3Anames%3Atc%3ASAML%3A2.0%3Aassertion%22%3E%3Csaml2%3AIssuer+Format%3D%22urn%3Aoasis%3Anames%3Atc%3ASAML%3A2.0%3Anameid-format%3Aentity%22%3Ehttps%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9443%2Fsamlsso%3C%2Fsaml2%3AIssuer%3E%3Csaml2%3ASubject%3E%3Csaml2%3ANameID%3Eadmin%3C%2Fsaml2%3ANameID%3E%3Csaml2%3ASubjectConfirmation+Method%3D%22urn%3Aoasis%3Anames%3Atc%3ASAML%3A2.0%3Acm%3Abearer%22%3E%3Csaml2%3ASubjectConfirmationData+InResponseTo%3D%220%22+NotOnOrAfter%3D%222013-07-02T09%3A37%3A45.635Z%22+Recipient%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fsaml2.demo%2Fconsumer%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsaml2%3ASubjectConfirmation%3E%3C%2Fsaml2%3ASubject%3E%3Csaml2%3AConditions+NotBefore%3D%222013-07-02T09%3A32%3A45.635Z%22+NotOnOrAfter%3D%222013-07-02T09%3A37%3A45.635Z%22%3E%3Csaml2%3AAudienceRestriction%3E%3Csaml2%3AAudience%3Esaml2.demo%3C%2Fsaml2%3AAudience%3E%3C%2Fsaml2%3AAudienceRestriction%3E%3C%2Fsaml2%3AConditions%3E%3Csaml2%3AAuthnStatement+AuthnInstant%3D%222013-07-02T09%3A32%3A45.635Z%22%3E%3Csaml2%3AAuthnContext%3E%3Csaml2%3AAuthnContextClassRef%3Eurn%3Aoasis%3Anames%3Atc%3ASAML%3A2.0%3Aac%3Aclasses%3APassword%3C%2Fsaml2%3AAuthnContextClassRef%3E%3C%2Fsaml2%3AAuthnContext%3E%3C%2Fsaml2%3AAuthnStatement%3E%3C%2Fsaml2%3AAssertion%3E%3C%2Fsaml2p%3AResponse%3E&RelayState=null
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Location: http://localhost:8080/saml2.demo/home.jsp?subject=admin
Content-Length: 0
Date: Tue, 02 Jul 2013 09:32:47 GMT
```

Here the `SAMLResponse` can be made visible by using a URL Decoder, for example [this one](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<saml2p:Response ID="dnfomflkhhdjjgfoggoagcdopgnjmpajenlehbka" IssueInstant="2013-07-02T09:32:45.635Z" Version="2.0" xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <saml2p:Status>
        <saml2p:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success"/>
    </saml2p:Status>
    <saml2:Assertion ID="dgamkdkadflnniggkelmjfakjljedhfdhnbpomdk" IssueInstant="2013-07-02T09:32:45.635Z" Version="2.0" xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
        <saml2:Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity">https://localhost:9443/samlsso</saml2:Issuer>
        <saml2:Subject>
            <saml2:NameID>admin</saml2:NameID>
            <saml2:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
                <saml2:SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="0" NotOnOrAfter="2013-07-02T09:37:45.635Z" Recipient="http://localhost:8080/saml2.demo/consumer"/>
            </saml2:SubjectConfirmation>
        </saml2:Subject>
        <saml2:Conditions NotBefore="2013-07-02T09:32:45.635Z" NotOnOrAfter="2013-07-02T09:37:45.635Z">
            <saml2:AudienceRestriction>
                <saml2:Audience>saml2.demo</saml2:Audience>
            </saml2:AudienceRestriction>
        </saml2:Conditions>
        <saml2:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2013-07-02T09:32:45.635Z">
            <saml2:AuthnContext>
                <saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password</saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>
            </saml2:AuthnContext>
        </saml2:AuthnStatement>
    </saml2:Assertion>
</saml2p:Response>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [WSO2 Identity Server - SAML SSO - Passive STS example not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15441987/wso2-identity-server-saml-sso-passive-sts-example-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

Even if this thread is old, I run into a similar Issue with the newer 5.1.0 Identity Server.

The SAMLRequest Url Parameter is decodable by first URL decode it and then Base64 inflate it e. g. on https://www.samltool.com/decode.php

There are other parameters in the Url, normally separated by "&" which must be excluded to get a successful decoding. In your example especially the "&relayState=null" at the end has to be excluded for decoding.

A redirect Binding would additionally have the deflated signature and the used digest algorithm as parameter.

This is the decoded and inflated result of the SAMLRequest param taken from question Code Snippet 1, it should cover the result from your SAML Debugger.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<samlp:AuthnRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"
    AssertionConsumerServiceURL="http://localhost:8080/saml2.demo/consumer"
    AttributeConsumingServiceIndex="1239245949" ForceAuthn="false" ID="0"
    IsPassive="false" IssueInstant="2013-07-02T09:32:15.619Z"
    ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
    Version="2.0">
    <samlp:Issuer xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">saml2.demo</samlp:Issuer>
    <samlp:NameIDPolicy AllowCreate="true"
    Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:persistent"
    SPNameQualifier="Isser" />
    <samlp:RequestedAuthnContext Comparison="exact">
        <saml:AuthnContextClassRef xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport
        </saml:AuthnContextClassRef>
    </samlp:RequestedAuthnContext>
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```